# Iterate through result set of method defined in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

report.rb

```
def archive
  Record.where('archive_id < ?', self.id)
end
```

report/show.html.haml

```
  %table
    %thead
        %th Record ID
        %th Description

    %tbody
    - @archives.each do |archive|
      %tr
        %td= archive.id
        %td= archive.description
```

I have an archive method defined in my reports model. In the reports show view I would like to iterate through the result set. How do I do this?

Comment: What you have here ought to work, you just need to initialize `@archives` in the controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def archives
  Record.where('archive_id < ?', self.id)
end


%table
    %thead
        %th Record ID
        %th Description

    %tbody
    - @report.archives.each do |archive|
      %tr
        %td= archive.id
        %td= archive.description
```

Instantiate @report in your reports_controller show action